# ¿Cómo introducir datos a un sistema de reglas como Drools?

Tags: java, drools, rabbit-mq

Tengo un pequeño sistema experto hecho con `Drools`, y tengo una duda, voy a intentar explicarla. El sistema reacciona ante diversos sensores. Recibe los valores de los sensores y actúa. Sé qué tengo que hacer para disparar todo el conjunto de reglas, pero mi duda surge cuando escalo la aplicación para que responda, por ejemplo, a cientos de sensores.

La idea es que el sistema experto esté escuchando siempre a todos los productores y que actúe en consecuencia con cada nuevo valor, que puede ser un valor clave.

¿Debo lanzar las reglas por cada uno de los valores de los sensores? ¿Debo meter los valores de los sensores en una cola, usando `RabbitMQ` por ejemplo, y lanzar todas las reglas por cada nuevo valor que vaya sacando de la cola? Si lanzo las reglas por cada valor de los sensores sin usar un gestor de colas como `RabbitMQ`, ¿cómo se que no perderé ningún valor?

Comment: Pondría más etiquetas, pero no encuentro ni Drools, ni RabbitMQ, ni Sistema Experto :(

Comment: @jj quizás es por tu puntuación, +1 por mi parte a la edición de Luiggi con las etiquetas extra ;)

Comment: Si, creo que era por mi puntuación. Aunque no se si por ser el sitio nuevo, las etiquetas no existían. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es muy similar con el manejo de PLC industriales. Hay software que manejan los sensores industriales como PLC, lectores de temperatura, etc. y la estrategia de estos es poner una capa intermedia entre los sensores y el consumidor.

La capa intermedia pregunta todo el tiempo a los sensores los valores. Si estos valores son diferentes a los valores anteriores, entonces los guarda.

Aclaro que los valores tienen un `timestamp` y un `quality-read` que son la fecha y hora del ultimo valor y la calidad de lectura de ese valor ya que, los sensores puede tirar *fruta*(valores no coherentes).

Todo esto es parte de estándar [OPC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPC).

En cuanto a la parte que expone para ser consumida, puede ser un simple WS como un RPC, Pipe o lo que quieras. Hasta puedes exponer eventos para que llamen a tu aplicacion y obtengan nuevos datos capturados.

Esta capa intermedia, que te menciono, es muy similar a un **OPC Server**.

Con respecto a `Drools`, no puedo decirte mucho, ya que no lo conozco. Si un motor de reglas de negocio, entonces no deberías tener ningún problema. Puede declarar una regla para que consuma un valor en particular de la capa intermedia y trabaje con ese dato.

Desde mi parte, trate de darte una aproximación al consumo de datos de dispositivos electrónicos. Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Es un poco la idea que tengo, usar una capa intermedia, preprocesar los valores y solo cuando tenga unos cuantos, enviarlos al motor de reglas. Gracias por tu respuesta. A ver si hay algún experto en Drools en el foro que me clarifique un poco el asunto